# I want to retrieve all folders which contains video files in listview ( Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-video-player

I want to show all folders which contain video files in a listview. I just want folders only not files. Please help me how can I do that in Android studio?

Comment: What have you tried and what specific problems have you encountered?

Comment: i have retrieved video files form external storage but dont know how to get folders only no files.

Comment: If you provide a [mcve] showing how you are building your list of video files, perhaps we can suggest modifications to your approach that will create the list of directories containing video files.

Answer (score 2):

it is possible using **MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI**

```
public ArrayList<VideoModel> getVideoFolders() {
        al_images.clear();

        int int_position = 0;
        Uri uri;
        Cursor cursor;
        int column_index_data, column_index_folder_name;

        String absolutePathOfImage = null;
        uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

        String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, MediaStore.Video.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME};

        final String orderBy = MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN;
        cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, orderBy + " DESC");

        column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
        column_index_folder_name = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            absolutePathOfImage = cursor.getString(column_index_data);
            Log.e("Column", absolutePathOfImage);
            Log.e("Folder", cursor.getString(column_index_folder_name));

            for (int i = 0; i < al_images.size(); i++) {
                if (al_images.get(i).getFolderName().equals(cursor.getString(column_index_folder_name))) {
                    boolean_folder = true;
                    int_position = i;
                    break;
                } else {
                    boolean_folder = false;
                }
            }


            if (boolean_folder) {

                ArrayList<String> al_path = new ArrayList<>();
                al_path.addAll(al_images.get(int_position).getVideoPath());
                al_path.add(absolutePathOfImage);
                al_images.get(int_position).setVideoPath(al_path);

            } else {
                ArrayList<String> al_path = new ArrayList<>();
                al_path.add(absolutePathOfImage);
                VideoModel obj_model = new VideoModel();
                obj_model.setFolderName(cursor.getString(column_index_folder_name));
                obj_model.setVideoPath(al_path);

                al_images.add(obj_model);


            }


        }


        for (int i = 0; i < al_images.size(); i++) {
            Log.e("FOLDER", al_images.get(i).getFolderName());
            for (int j = 0; j < al_images.get(i).getVideoPath().size(); j++) {
                Log.e("FILE", al_images.get(i).getVideoPath().get(j));
            }
        }

        return al_images;
    }
```

Model Class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class VideoModel {
    String FolderName;
    ArrayList<String> VideoPath;

    public String getFolderName() {
        return FolderName;
    }

    public void setFolderName(String folderName) {
        FolderName = folderName;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getVideoPath() {
        return VideoPath;
    }

    public void setVideoPath(ArrayList<String> videoPath) {
        VideoPath = videoPath;
    }
}
```